# cloud function file name

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy `Cloud Function`. I have written the function in file called `gcpapp.py`.

When I try to deploy this function, it gives me an error saying `Deployment failure:
Function load error: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist`.

I entered `appgcp.main` as `Function to execute` where `appgcp` is the file name and `main` is the function name.

Do I must name the file where the function resides as `main.py`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must name your file main.py.  According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime#source_code_structure):

> **Source code structure**
>
> Your function's entrypoint must be defined in a Python source file
>   named main.py.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: I will point out that there's nothing stopping you from having other files that contain the code for your functions.  You just have to import and call them from main.py.